# returning ints from a handler

Tags: java

I have a very, very messed up method. I want to return `ints` from a handler. My code is like this:

```
public void getCasesFromFolder() {

    msg = handler.obtainMessage();


    timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
          public void run(){
              if(folder.list().length == 0)  {
                  msg.obj = "0";
                  handler.sendMessage(msg);
              }

              else {
                    msg.obj = Integer.toString(folder.list().length) ;
                    handler.sendMessage(msg);
              }

          }
    }, delay, 3000);
}

private Handler handler = new Handler() {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message m) {

        String message = (String) m.obj;
        if(message.equals("0")) {
            returnValues(0); 
        }
        else {
            returnValues(Integer.parseInt(message));
        }

    }

    public int returnValues(int i) {

        if(i == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return i; 

    }
};
```

This doesn't work, of course. How can I return a int from a handler?

Comment: It might help if you share more background on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `int` attribute in the class, and make your handler set its value in `handleMessage()` method instead of returning it.

By the way your `returnValues(`) method is completely useless as it can be simplified to just `return i;` which does nothing but return the parameter.

Comment: +1 For attempting to actually suggest a workaround, rather than bluntly stating it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `void` cannot return anything.  Also this function:

```
public int returnValues(int i) {

        if(i == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return i; 

    }
```

does absolutely nothing.  Further you are not manipulating the object in any way.  You are invoking a function `returnValues` that does not perform a mutation (or set operation) on any attribute of the `Handler` object.  This means that when `returnValues` is called you are just discarding the result since it will fall out of scope.

Comment: Handler being an interface he implements, chances are the signature method is not to be changed. And what he apparently wants is a way to access the int from the current class after the method is executed, which he will not being able to do with this solution.

Comment: @KayKay and what exactly in my response was incorrect?  Void doesn't return anything and his axillary function also does nothing.  I explicitly stated OP needs a mutator.  In fact my answer is almost identical to yours, so I don't see the gripe.

Comment: I never said it is incorrect. I just said it is not solving the problem.

Comment: @KayKay what part was missing from my explanation about how to solve the problem?  `You are invoking a function returnValues that does not perform a mutation (or set operation) on any attribute of the Handler ` 

lays it out there what needs to happen.

Comment: The problem is to access the value from outside the handler method. Nothing you said helps with that. The returnValues method has nothing to do with his problem despite being a useless method.